# Handling nested variable scopes when implementing an interpreter

Tags: haskell, interpreter

I'm currently writing an interpreter for a simple programming language and just wanted to ask on the best approach would be to tackle it.

The environment for a program is as follows:

```
type Env = [[(Var, Int)]]
```

So I've coded the `lookup` and `update` but I'm a bit stuck on how to deal with the the scope for each begin block. An example is shown below:

```
begin [a,b,c] 
    read i
    n = 1
    while i < 0 do
        begin
        n = 2 * n
        i = i - 1
        end;
    write n
end
```

From my understanding the scope of the first begin would be [a,b,c,i,n]
and then the second begin would contain [i, n]

therefore the env would be

```
[ [ ("a",0), (b",0), ("c",0), ("i",3), ("n",2) ], [("n",8), ("i",0) ]    ]`
```

Currently my lookup function returns the first occurrence of a variable, so I'm having problems with the 2nd scope (2nd begin).

I'm not quite sure how I can make the `update` and `lookup` function return the value associated with that particular scope.

Basically I have the code working for one `begin` statement, but I am having issues with 2 or more statements in the sample program.

Comment: Presumably you want to access the value associated with a variable in the most recently defined `begin` block. Therefore the environment in the first `begin` block should be `[a,b,c,i,n]` whilst in the second `begin` block you have `[[i,n],[a,b,c,i,n]]`. When you are in the second block, looking up the values of `i` and `n` gets the local version (defined in the first element of the list) but looking up `a`, `b` and `c` gets the version in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was thinking about that. Currently my lookup function only returns the first occurence of a repeated variable. I thought about doing the search backward but this won't work for reading values from the first scope.
I'm not quite sure how I would update a variable from a given scope. At the moment my function updates all variables with the same letter.

Comment: Your lookup function works fine, assuming the inner environment is the first one in the list. Your update function allows you to modify variables outside of the current scope - is this what you intended? For example, with `env = [[("a",1)], [("a",2),("b",3)]]` I would expect `lookup "a" env` to return `1` (it does), `lookup "b" env` to return `3` (it does), `update "a" 4 env` to return `[[("a",4)], [("a",2),("b",3)]]` (it does) and `update "b" 4 env` to throw some kind of error (at the moment it returns `[[("a",1)], [("a",2),("b",4)]]` - is this what you intend?)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll make the changes you suggested. I should also remove the scope of the second begin block once it has been executed.

I think it's better to have the enviroment as you said [[i,n],[a,b,c,i,n]] and not [[a,b,c,i,n], [i,n]]

Comment: I think you should check on the scoping rules of the language. Hopefully your instructor has made that clear. If not ask them. The standard thing is this: since the inner block declares no variables, the i and n variables referenced in the inner block are same as the the ones referenced in an outer block.  Second, since i and n aren't declared anywhere, are they errors or implicitly declared and if the latter in what block?  I think the env, while interpreting the inner block, (leaving out values) may be (assuming outer block last) [[], [a,b,c], [i,n]] or [[], [a, b, c, i, n]] or [[],[a,b,c]].

Comment: Yeah, it's not very clear from the description. That's why I posted here on the best way to go about it. I'm a bit confused now on how I should tackle the scoping. Initially I had the scope for each begin left to right. I can't ask any instructors since it's not really homework. It was last year's coursework for a course I may take next semester. I was trying to do as practice for learning Haskell.

Comment: And the sample program contains 2 begin statements. I am assuming that they can be declared as begin [a,b,c,i,n] in the outer block. Or you can add it to the scope when the assignment is made.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `while i > 0` ? Unless I'm reading it wrong it'd be an infinite loop the way you have it. (Is the example the same way?)